# Format number to string

Tags: vb.net

I have to format number to exact this format "###,###,###.##" and try to write program like this:

```
Dim myNum as double = 1255.32
Debug.Print(myNum.ToString("###,###,###.##"))
```

I can do .PadLeft to ensure aligning with fixed-width font but my number is not showed correctly with this format string.
If I write that by using "##0.00" then I haven't thousand separator showed.

In earlier Basic versions that was easy but...
How to get number showed in this format in VB.NET?

If is important my local decimal "point" is "," (comma).

Example:

```
                First source    Second source
            ---------------- ---------------- 
 Price:            97.419,52        97.419,26 
   Tax:             4.870,98         4.870,96 
Brutto:           102.290,50       102.290,24 

                 Temp source                 
            ----------------                 
 Price:                 0,00   
   Tax:                 0,00       Difference          
Brutto:                 0,00           - 0,26
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CultureInfo` gives you much more control on the number format. Sample code:

```
Dim culture As Globalization.CultureInfo = New Globalization.CultureInfo(Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name)
culture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "."
culture.NumberFormat.NumberGroupSeparator = ","

Dim myNum As Double = 1255.32
Debug.Print(myNum.ToString("N", culture))
```

Comment: Hi varocarbas. That actually work but here I also should define padding to left for each number to ensure aligning? As I can see VB already know my CultureInfo so using only "N" is enough?

Comment: @user973238 Please, write down a sample output to explain exactly what you mean with "aligning" (if it is what I think; the proposed code would account for it automatically). Regarding using only ToString("N"), note that it would take the properties from the culture in the given computer (Croatian, I presume), that is, it might work (if the properties are as you wish) or not. My code defines a new culture just for the given writing including the properties you want, that is, it will work for sure independently upon the culture in the given computer.

Comment: Thanks for that huge explanation. In this case I have to show some numbers (added in question) in pure textbox which have to be aligned as showed. I may use html and webbrowser control but I decide to use textbox without any important reason. Of course, I'm trying to use new .NET methods as much I can, still learning that system.

Comment: @user973238 Lastly, I want to highlight that you should always try to use the VB.NET instead of the VB6 ones (even though it also supported by VB.NET), as far as it is newer and usually represents a better approach (with many more options). In this case, for example, you are thinking in the "VB6 way" (with the aligning thing; although you have to clarify this point); in VB.NET, usually, you have a property to take care of any issue and in CultureInfo you have plently of properties... (I have rewritten my comments because the previous ones weren't too clear)

Comment: Luckily, we have proportional font in code window of SO so you can see my "aligning".

Comment: @user973238 You mean aligment of the text? This has nothing to do with the number format, but with a property of the given control you are using. If you use a textbox, you have to use its text alignment property, but you are using Debug.Print... This is not what the original question was about (and you know: one question per post). If you write your whole code I can give you some hints, although it seems like your ideas are not too clear: one thing is the format of the given string (by bringing the culture into account or not)...

Comment: @user973238 and another thing is the alignment of the text which is taken care of by the given control. If the given control does not have  such a feature (or you are not using a control, but just writing to the Console or to a file or something like this), you would have to add tabs (or spaces) to synchronise everything; or something equivalent. But this has nothing to do with ToString().

Comment: Thanks Varo, with "N" and PadLeft i solve my problem by using iTax.ToString("N").PadLeft(14). I work on complex and huge program and it is often hard to isolate concrete code so I make an suitable example. I also use proportional font (Courier New) for this "report" so now is thing aligned as should be. I have to admit here is MUCH problems with .NET but day by day - less and less... Thanks for helping.

Comment: @user973238 OK. If you use a textbox (or a richtextbox) you might do some alignment but if you want "various columns" in the same line you would have to write some space in between (PadLeft or vbCrLf or similar); or rely on a control accepting columns (e.g., ListView). You should have posted your whole code such that I might give you some advice. Also note that Tostring("N") MIGHT not work if the conditions change (you use the app in a different computer or change the Culture settings); better rely on the whole code I wrote.

Comment: Well, it is not too difficult but here are much things which you simply have to know (and pass it) since are different from anything before such is format specifier "N" instead of earlier format string "###.##0,00". That is not "intuitive", that is "fact".

Comment: @user973238 What I meant with intuitive was CultureInfo (if you take a look at all the properties inside the culture variable in my code you would see that have full control on everything). "N" stands for numeric (as opossed to "C" for currency), but this is not too common in VB.NET (I mean, having to write a specific character); usually you have a bunch of options (like in culture).

Comment: @user973238 PS: note that the reason why you have to type "N" (or "C") is precisely because the high number of options you have: the thousand separator can be defined differently for any of these types (in my code, I am defining the thousands separator for numbers: .NumberGroupSeparator; there is a different property for currency). VB.NET assumes that if you don't specify either number of currency, you don't want to use thousands separator at all.